# Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused

Tags: iptables, firewall, port-forwarding

I am unable to connect to port 80 on an ec2 VM.

I even tried this below command.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

But no change in the response.

My security group inbound rules also say
HTTP TCP 80 anywhere.

Is there anything else I can do to open port 80?

Comment: Are you able to SSH into the EC2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `sudo ufw stop`? `ufw` is a builtin firewall program that may be blocking your access. Also make sure that 127.0.0.1 isn't be assigned to some other address in `/etc/hosts`